# Find specific node in parse tree depending on children it has

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

To automate a security review of C# code, I want to retrieve all methods from controllers that do have a `[HttpPost]` attribute, but do not have a `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute. I am using ANTLR to get a ParseTree of the C# code. When I have that, what is the best way to obtain the nodes that have a HttpPost child but not a ValidateAntiForgeryToken child?

I have tried XPath, but it seems ANTLR only supports a subset of XPath. I am considering converting the parse tree to XML and use real XPath on it. Is there an easier way?

I am using the following code to parse the C# file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.xpath.*;

public class MyParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        CharStream input = CharStreams.fromFileName(args[0]);
        Lexer lexer = new CSharpLexer(input);
        TokenStream stream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        CSharpParser parser = new CSharpParser(stream);
        ParseTree tree = parser.compilation_unit();

        String xpath = "//class_member_declaration";
        Collection<ParseTree> matches = XPath.findAll(tree, xpath, parser);
        System.out.println(matches);
    }
}
```

The tree looks like this:

[image: ANTLR parse tree]

Comment: [Parse Tree Matching and XPath](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/tree-matching.md) provides some ways to find specific nodes.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/551) is about full XPath support in ANTLR4.

Answer (score 2):

Antlr4 does not support fancy matching on the ParseTree besides a subset of XPath. However, that is also probably the wrong way to solve this problem.

For most use cases, you should walk through the parse tree and collect the information you want. This can be done using a listener or a visitor. For example, the following code collects methods and attributes and prints methods that have certain attributes:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyListener extends CSharpParserBaseListener {
    String currentClass = null;
    String currentMethod = null;
    List<String> attributes;
    boolean inClassMember = false;

    @Override public void enterClass_definition(CSharpParser.Class_definitionContext ctx) { 
        this.currentClass = ctx.identifier().getText();
    }

    // Class member declaration. This thing holds both the attributes and the method declaration.
    @Override public void enterClass_member_declaration(CSharpParser.Class_member_declarationContext ctx) { 
        this.attributes = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.inClassMember = true;
    }

    @Override public void enterAttribute(CSharpParser.AttributeContext ctx) { 
        if (this.inClassMember) {
            String attrName = ctx.namespace_or_type_name().identifier().get(0).getText();
            this.attributes.add(attrName);
        }
    }

    @Override public void enterMethod_declaration(CSharpParser.Method_declarationContext ctx) { 
        this.currentMethod = ctx.method_member_name().identifier().get(0).getText();
    }

    // In the exit we have collected our method name and attributes.
    @Override public void exitClass_member_declaration(CSharpParser.Class_member_declarationContext ctx) {
        if (this.attributes.contains("HttpPost") && !this.attributes.contains("ValidateAntiForgeryToken")) {
            System.out.println(this.currentClass + "." + this.currentMethod);
        }

        this.attributes = null;
        this.currentMethod = null;
        this.inClassMember = false;
    }   
}
```

To make this more versatile, a better approach would be to convert the parse tree to another tree (i.e. abstract syntax tree) and search that tree for the information you want.

Answer (score 1):

> I am considering converting the parse tree to XML and use real XPath on it. Is there an easier way?

There is no need to convert a tree to actual XML in order to use XPath queries. The Apache Commons libary [JXPath](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/) supports XPath queries on in-memory trees of Java objects.